# Настройка плагина eCSStractor при включенном Prettier

Tags: visual-studio-code

Прошу помощи разобраться с настройка плагина eCSStractor
Вопрос состоит в следующем при вставке классов в style.css c использованием eCSStractor он вставляет класс в такой форме:

```
.test{
}
```

Нужно настроить плагин таким образом чтобы при вставке классов c использованием eCSStractor между фигурных скобок была пустая строка, а именно:

```
.test{

}
```

Проблему частично удалось решить откорректировав файл C:\Users<user>.vscode\extensions\diz.ecsstractor-port-0.0.3extension.js. В блоке else необходимо было дописать между открывающей и закрывающей скобками ещё один \n, что означает новая строка

```
if (!brackets_newline_after) {
  var cleanString = `.${classToAdd} ${open_bracket}${close_bracket}`;
} else {
  var cleanString = `.${classToAdd} ${open_bracket}\n\n${close_bracket}`;
}
```

Но при включенном плагине Prettier пустая строка схопывается и остается такого формата

```
.test{
}
```